# How to register a push notifications for a pass

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

I have read Passbook web service reference, but I don't know to implement it. How we use the parameters such as webserviceURL, version, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your web service as per the documentation then add your webserviceURL and an authenticationToken key to your pass.json.

Then when your pass is insalled in a device, the device will call your web service to register the deviceID and deviceToken.

A couple of things to watch for:

- for production, your web service must use https (you can use http for development by setting a toggle in the developer settings on your test device)
- the iOS simulator doesn't call the web service, all web service testing needs to be done on a device

Comment: could you add some details for creating web service ?

Comment: Would help to know what language you want to use?  There are a number of open source projects you could use [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Passbook_(application)&oldid=541289590#Developer_tools)

Comment: I want to use php, so should I follow this one: https://code.google.com/p/passkit/wiki/PassProcessingPHPExample

Comment: No, this one is for use with our PassKit API to manipulate passes created and distributed with our [pass designer](https://create.passkit.com).  If you want to build your own web service, then try [this tutorial](http://blog.garethj.com/2009/02/17/building-a-restful-web-application-with-php/).  You will also need code to generate passes on your server and a database that you can query to store the device IDs and tokens and to determine the serials of passes that require updating for each device.  If you want to be able to push updates, you will need to also build a push notification Service.